# Specify path to fsi.exe when creating FsiEvaluationSession

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

As documented [here](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/issues/420), the first argument to to the argument in the array `allArgs` specifying the path to fsi.exe is ignored:

```
let argv = [| "C:\\fsi.exe" |]
let allArgs = Array.append argv [|"--noninteractive"|]

let fsiConfig = FsiEvaluationSession.GetDefaultConfiguration()
let fsiSession = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)
```

Is there anyway to specify this argument - i.e. specify the location of fsi.exe to be used during the evaluation?

The reason I want to do this is so I can target a specific version of fsi.exe included in the FSharp.Compiler.Tools nuget package.

Comment: `fsi.exe` is not used at all. It's all a library.

Comment: Thank you - that's really useful to know.